# Assigning 3 dots argument to array in angular 5

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular5, angular-changedetection

I came across a line in Angular
What does it mean?

```
this.columns = [...this.columns, col];
```

I think this is related to immutable concept of array.

Comment: This is part of JavaScript, it's called [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: it will make copy of columns, and append new col. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: It is used in Angular Change detection ? you can refer the link https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/change-detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...` is a destructuring assignment in JavaScript, not only in Angular. It makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

`this.columns` must be an object or array in order for it to be valid. It gets all the values or properties from `this.columns` and creates separate variables for each of them. 
From your code, its apparent that it most likely is an array.

The code does this:
Unpacks the current values from `this.columns`, creates a new array with these elements, and adding col, and assigns it to `this.columns`.

In other words, that code adds `col` to `this.columns`.